# layout_weight inconsistency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

My app should look like this:

[image]

This is how it should look, though the way I had it before it wasn't scaling well. So that's why I am doing this, but it is giving me lots of problems.

But with even seemingly identical setups, the second row takes up all of the room, making it look like this:

[image]

Any explanation why it is doing this? It beats me.
Here is my XML, any solutions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:weightSum="7.0"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/terranlogo1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/terranlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/protosslogo1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/protosslogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/zerglogo" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_p1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />
 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/terranlogo2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/terranlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/protosslogo2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/protosslogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zerglogo2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/zerglogo" />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout06"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_t2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_p2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout07"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose your opponets race(s) and your race(s)" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout08"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Game Length"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Mistakes Allowed"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Answer Time"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout09"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_answertime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
 />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_mistakenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
 />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_gametime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
 />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just an advice, don't give container layout height 0dp, cause it has children in it. have it "wrap_content"

Comment: Why are the weights all equal? You want the checkboxes to be just as tall as the images? I don't understand - this is not what the first image shows.

Comment: Maxim, layout_height should be set to 0dp on the child LinearLayout elements, as it avoids the second pass to calculate layout heights. This is recommended via the Lint tool.

Comment: Matt, I do not want them to be the same size. I just have it set as that for simplicity in experimenting as to why the images aren't consistent.

Comment: @tad "Lint tool" can you provide a link to the recomendation? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Every your child LinearLayout has android:layout_weight="1.0" which mean to take even space for every child. Get rid of it first. Let Layouts get as much space as they need. Also android:weightSum="7.0" it will be calculated based on children's weight

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height on the middle LinearLayout is set to wrap_content, which is not what you want. Set all immediate children of the root LinearLayout to layout_height="0dp" and you will get all items evenly distributed in height.

Also, the weightSum=7 is unneeded if you intend for all elements to take up 100% of the container height.

See http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can't believe that I didn't see that wrap_content.